# apply_filters not echoing list items in Unorderd List

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using wordpress `apply_filters` hook for attaching an action hook.My code is to echo lists if some links in a `ul` tag.(if woocommerce active).

My code goes here

```
$loggedin_item = '<div>';
    $loggedin_item .= $user_dp; //it works & its none of this questions business
    $loggedin_item .= '<ul>';
        apply_filters( 'after_user_loggedin_menu', $is_wc_active, $is_logged_in ); //its not working
    $loggedin_item .= '</ul>';
$loggedin_item .= '</div>';
```

and my attachment function is here.If i use echo it echos outside `ul` and if i use return it does not echo anything

```
function wc_action_header( $is_wc_active, $is_logged_in ){
    $wc_li = '';
    if( $is_wc_active){
        $my_account_url = get_permalink( get_option('woocommerce_myaccount_page_id') );
        $wc_account_items = wc_get_account_menu_items();
        foreach ($wc_account_items as $key => $value) {
            $wc_li .= '<li><a href="' . $my_account_url . $key . '">'. esc_attr($value) .'</a></li>'; 
        }
    }
    echo $wc_li; 
}
```

and adding hooks

```
add_filter('after_user_loggedin_menu', array($this, 'wc_action_header' ), 10, 2);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're storing your HTML in `$loggedin_item` var, you need to add `wc_action_header` output to this var.

```php
$loggedin_item = '<div>';
    $loggedin_item .= $user_dp; //it works & its none of this questions business
    $loggedin_item .= '<ul>';

    $output = '';
    $output = apply_filters( 'after_user_loggedin_menu', $is_wc_active, $is_logged_in );
    $loggedin_item.=$output;

    $loggedin_item .= '</ul>';
$loggedin_item .= '</div>';
```

And change `echo $wc_li;` to `return $wc_li;` in your `wc_action_header` function.